# Emulator to inspect an element on the outlook

Tags: css, email, outlook, frontend

I am working with e-mail templates, and the client tests on outlook 2019, gmail and yahoo.

Is there any way to inspect the element in outlook-2019 ? I know this can't be done on the actual app, but maybe some kind of emulator or something similar ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any of these popular tools:

1 - Litmus https://litmusapp.com/
2 - MailChimp https://www.mailchimp.com/
3 - CampaignMonitor https://www.campaignmonitor.com/
4 - testi https://testi.at/
5 - Email on Acid @ https://www.emailonacid.com/